# Swift Audio passing to another ViewController

Tags: swift, xcode, audio, segue, viewcontroller

```
override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) { 
    if segue.identifier == "stopRecording" {             
        let playSoundsVC = segue.destination as! PlaySoundsViewController          
        let recordedAudioURL = sender as! URL           
        playSoundsVC.receivedAudio = recordedAudioURL               
    }
}
```

The question is that my Xcode generating error

> Value of type 'PlaySoundsViewController' has no member 'receivedAudio'

Comment: Is there a variable called receivedAudio in PlaySoundsViewController ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For this to work the destinationVC should look like this

```
class PlaySoundsViewController:UIViewController {

    var receivedAudio:URL?

    .....
 }
```